# Uploading a photo from another server directy to Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, upload, image

Im trying to do a simple script with this:

[How-To: Use the Graph API to Upload Photos to a user’s profile](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/)

But my problem is two things:

1. I want the users to be able to send the pictures from my site to facebook with out having to download it and then upload it
2. I would like to have a diferent respond insted the number one gets from facebook

I seen some pages do this,

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc says "you can upload a photo by issuing an HTTP POST request with the photo content and an optional description". Try perhaps with the image's web url. According to [this](http://daipratt.co.uk/facebook-api-upload-photo/), it should work.

For the second, you should use [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object).

Comment: Thanks man, it word... just needed a little editing but the basic idea was the same, thanks a lot!