# POST with submit input an image src instead of an input of type file

Tags: html, image, http-post, form-submit

I have a form with a submit input that send a POST request with an image and a extra description. It all works fine but this is not the purpose that I am looking for. I don't want the user to choose an image from his PC, instead to provide with an image that is already on my server. I've tried with a hidden input but with no success. Here is my code:

```
<img src="final.jpg">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<php echo $graph_url; ?>" method="POST">
    Please choose a photo: 
    <input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>
    Say something about this photo: 
    <input name="message" type="text" value=""><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br/>
</form>
```

I want that final.jpg to be send instead of the file that comes in the file input type. I mentioned before that the hidden type doesn't work for me or I didn't use it like it should. Hope I make myself very clear.

Comment: How is the user supposed to select the image on your server? Copy and paste a URL somewhere?

Comment: Then you should not let him choose a file from his PC.. You should make a file selector which will let the user choose from the files on your server.

Comment: The idea is that the user isn't supposed to choose anything. The image will be displayed above the form so he will know what he POST.

Comment: Not sure of what you want, but if the image is already on your server, you just have to send its path via an hidden input, and instead of uploading it with PHP, just copy (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.copy.php) it/use its path in the $graph_url page.

Comment: The user in my case create an image that is finally on my server (final.jpg in the upper example). After that If he like it in the preview to POST it to his facebook in an album create previously by my app in which the final image will be. I don't want him to choose other image from his PC or my server, I just want that only the "preview" image to be uploaded and I can do this for the moment only with the input of file type.

Comment: Take a look at the two links in the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148155/uploading-a-photo-from-another-server-directy-to-facebook